# partial show table view cell content swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, tablecell

[image]

> I don't know why this issue is happened.Cell Content show partial data. I returned number of rows is section 5. and I used custom view inside table cell content view.

Answer (score 0):

Your table view might not have proper constraints which could cause it to be cut off at the bottom as seen in your screenshot.

If this table view takes up the whole view controller, adding constraints that align the sides to the safe area (like in the screenshot below) might help.

[image: Example constraints of table view]